# How to read in FBX 2014 indices properly for DirectX?

Tags: c++, directx, mesh, indices, fbx

I've been having this very annoying problem for the past weekend. I have to be able to to read in a triangulated 2014 FBX file that contains a mesh exported from Maya and read in it's vertices and indices to be passed to the renderer (DirectX) for the **DrawIndexed** call.

So the way I have it setup is that there is a **TUniqueVertex** structure

```
struct TUniqueVertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 m_vPosition,   // Vertex positions
    XMFLOAT3 m_vNormal,     // Vertex normals
    XMFLOAT2 m_UVs          // Vertex UVs
    int m_nControlPointIndex, // Control Point Index
 }
```

This code here, will load in the FbxMesh into a **CMesh** class. Which holds the mesh's vertices and indices.

```
 class CMesh
 {
     ...
    vector<TUniqueVertex> m_vVertices;
    vector<unsigned int> m_vIndices;
 }
```

The code to load into the **CMesh**:

```
bool LoadMesh(FbxMesh* pMesh, CMesh cMesh)
{
    int polygonCount = pMesh->GetPolygonCount();        
    FbxVector4* controlPoints = pMesh->GetControlPoints();
    int controlPointCount = pMesh->GetControlPointsCount();

    int vertexID = 0;

    for (int polygon = 0; polygon < polygonCount; polygon++)
    {
        int polyVertCount = pMesh->GetPolygonSize(polygon);

    for (int polyVert = 0; polyVert < polyVertCount; polyVert++)
    {
        CMesh::TUniqueVertex uniqueVert;

        int cpIndex = pMesh->GetPolygonVertex(polygon, polyVert);

        // Grab our CP index as well our position information
        uniqueVert.m_nControlPointIndex = cpIndex;
        uniqueVert.m_vPosition = 
        XMFLOAT3((float)controlPoints[cpIndex].mData[0],
                 (float)controlPoints[cpIndex].mData[1],
                 (float)controlPoints[cpIndex].mData[2]);

        // Grab UVs
        int uvElementCount = pMesh->GetElementUVCount();

        for (int uvElement = 0; uvElement < uvElementCount; uvElement++)
        {
            FbxGeometryElementUV* geomElementUV = pMesh>GetElementUV(uvElement);

            FbxLayerElement::EMappingMode mapMode = geomElementUV->GetMappingMode();
            FbxLayerElement::EReferenceMode refMode = geomElementUV->GetReferenceMode();

            int directIndex = -1;

            if (FbxGeometryElement::eByControlPoint == mapMode)
            {
                if (FbxGeometryElement::eDirect == refMode)
                {
                    directIndex = cpIndex;
                }
                else if (FbxGeometryElement::eIndexToDirect == refMode)
                {
                    directIndex = geomElementUV->GetIndexArray().GetAt(cpIndex);
                }
            }
            else if (FbxGeometryElement::eByPolygonVertex == mapMode)
            {
                if (FbxGeometryElement::eDirect == refMode || FbxGeometryElement::eIndexToDirect == refMode)
                {
                    directIndex = pMesh->GetTextureUVIndex(polygon, polyVert);
                }

            }

            // If we got a UV index
            if (directIndex != -1)
            {
                FbxVector2 uv = geomElementUV->GetDirectArray().GetAt(directIndex);

                uniqueVert.m_UVs = XMFLOAT2( (float)uv.mData[0],
                                             (float)uv.mData[1]);
            }
        }

        // Grab normals
        int normElementCount = pMesh->GetElementNormalCount();

        for (int normElement = 0; normElement < normElementCount; normElement++)
        {
            FbxGeometryElementNormal* geomElementNormal = pMesh->GetElementNormal(normElement);

            FbxLayerElement::EMappingMode mapMode = geomElementNormal->GetMappingMode();
            FbxLayerElement::EReferenceMode refMode = geomElementNormal->GetReferenceMode();

            int directIndex = -1;

            if (FbxGeometryElement::eByPolygonVertex == mapMode)
            {
                if (FbxGeometryElement::eDirect == refMode)
                {
                    directIndex = vertexID;
                }
                else if (FbxGeometryElement::eIndexToDirect == refMode)
                {
                    directIndex = geomElementNormal->GetIndexArray().GetAt(vertexID);
                }
            }

            // If we got an index
            if (directIndex != 1)
            {
                FbxVector4 norm = geomElementNormal->GetDirectArray().GetAt(directIndex);

                uniqueVert.m_vNormal = XMFLOAT3((float)norm.mData[0],
                                                (float)norm.mData[1],
                                                (float)norm.mData[2]);

            }
        }

        // Unique Vertices stuff
        vector<CMesh::TUniqueVertex>& uniqueVerts = cMesh.GetVertices();

        size_t size = uniqueVerts.size();
        size_t i;

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (uniqueVert == uniqueVerts[i])
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == size)
        {
            uniqueVerts.push_back(uniqueVert);
        }

        cMesh.GetIndices().push_back(i);
        ++vertexID;
    }
}

return true;
}
```

Doing this method loads in the vertices, normals, and UVs correctly. However, when loading in the indices and passing the cMesh.GetIndices() count to the **DrawIndexed** call, the indices are completely out of order and looks like this in the graphic debugger:

[image: Graphic Debugger]

Incase anyone is wondering, the indices are as follows:

012, 023, 456, 657, 891, 081, 011, 121, 314, 121, 415, 161, 718, 171, 918, 202, 122, 212, 023

And here is the test .fbx that I'm trying to load the information from:

[Cube.fbx direct download](https://mega.co.nz/#!sIcjmS4A!eeNO-1q8_uN1Be5fsyUafLyIMoDqLQ6n3FWwVMNtW_w)

If anyone can help me out with this, I'd be extremely grateful as this issue has caused me so much stress :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using left-handed view coordinates or right-handed view coordinates in your application (see [link](https://www.evl.uic.edu/ralph/508S98/coordinates.html))? If you are using left-handed view coordinates, you need to flip the winding of each triangle in the index buffer.

```
    assert( (indices.size() % 3) == 0 );
    for( auto it = indices.begin(); it != indices.end(); it += 3 )
    {
        std::swap( *it, *(it+2) );
    }
```

You may also need to flip the texture coordinates as well:

```
    for( auto it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it )
    {
        it->textureCoordinate.x = ( 1.f - it->textureCoordinate.x );
    }
```

Historically most DirectX applications use left-handed view coordinates. XNA Game Studio and most OpenGL applications use right-handed view coordinates.

BTW, this is why both `-fliptriangles+` and `-invertvtexcoord+` are enabled by default in the [Samples Content Exporter](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=226208) for SDKMESH.